# What's wrong with this .htaccess code that is blocking all traffic to my site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-analytics

I want to block some of the more notorious referral traffic spammers from accessing my site by banning them via my `.htaccess` file. I added the following code to my `.htaccess`, but it resulted in *all* traffic being blocked. Where did I go wrong? Please note that the code below is derived from copying and pasting from code found on the web, as I am not that familiar with Apache configurations.

```
## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 4webmasters.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} trafficmonetizer.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} traffic2money.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} webmonetizer.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} success-seo.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Also, I have added the above URLs to my *Referral Exclusion List* in Google's Analytics interface. If anyone has further tips for getting this annoying sites to stop cluttering up my Analytics data, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to just comment your post, so i'll just leave this suggestion here:

The last OR flag might make the RewriteRule always execute. Can you try to remove it ?

```
## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 4webmasters.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} trafficmonetizer.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} traffic2money.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} webmonetizer.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} success-seo.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```